# Unable to connect Kibana to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I've installed ES 7.5 and Kibana 7.5 on RHEL7, but after starting Kibana and checking the UI, I'm seeing the error, "Kibana server is not ready yet."

Checking the Kibana log, I see that it is not properly connecting to ES. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the output of *journalctl --unit kibana*:

```
Dec 11 10:03:05 mcjca033031 systemd[1]: kibana.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 11 10:03:05 mcjca033031 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Dec 11 10:03:05 mcjca033031 systemd[1]: Starting Kibana...
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":5320,"message":"Setting up [15] plugins: [security,licensing,code,timelion,features,spaces,translation
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["info","plugins","security"],"pid":5320,"message":"Setting up plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["warning","plugins","security","config"],"pid":5320,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent s
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["warning","plugins","security","config"],"pid":5320,"message":"Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["info","plugins","licensing"],"pid":5320,"message":"Setting up plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["info","plugins","code"],"pid":5320,"message":"Setting up plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["info","plugins","timelion"],"pid":5320,"message":"Setting up plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["info","plugins","features"],"pid":5320,"message":"Setting up plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["info","plugins","spaces"],"pid":5320,"message":"Setting up plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["info","plugins","translations"],"pid":5320,"message":"Setting up plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:08 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:08Z","tags":["info","plugins","data"],"pid":5320,"message":"Setting up plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:13 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:13Z","tags":["warning","legacy-plugins"],"pid":5320,"path":"/usr/share/kibana/src/legacy/core_plugins/visualizations","message":"Skipping non-plug
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["warning","plugins","licensing"],"pid":5320,"message":"License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch for the [data] cl
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":5320,"message":"Starting [8] plugins: [security,licensing,code,timelion,features,spaces,translations,d
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","migrations"],"pid":5320,"message":"Creating index .kibana_task_manager_1."}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","migrations"],"pid":5320,"message":"Creating index .kibana_1."}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["warning","migrations"],"pid":5320,"message":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Error: [mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for ty
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["fatal","root"],"pid":5320,"message":"{ Error: [mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [flattened] declared on field [state]\n
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins-system"],"pid":5320,"message":"Stopping all plugins."}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins","data"],"pid":5320,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins","translations"],"pid":5320,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins","spaces"],"pid":5320,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins","features"],"pid":5320,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins","timelion"],"pid":5320,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins","code"],"pid":5320,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins","licensing"],"pid":5320,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-12-11T15:03:14Z","tags":["info","plugins","security"],"pid":5320,"message":"Stopping plugin"}
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: FATAL  [mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [flattened] declared on field [state] :: {"path":"/.kibana_1","query":{},"body":"{\"mappings\":{\"dynamic\":\"strict\",\"properties\":{\"
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: \":{\"type\":\"geo_shape\"},\"mapStateJSON\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"layerListJSON\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"uiStateJSON\":{\"type\":\"text\"}}},\"maps-telemetry\":{\"properties\":{\"mapsTotalCou
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: \":\"keyword\"},\"color\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"label\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"}}},\"limit\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"groupBy\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"filterQuery\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: displayValue\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"operator\":{\"type\":\"text\"}}},\"and\":{\"properties\":{\"id\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"name\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"enabled\":{\"type\":\"boolean\"},\"
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: \":\"long\",\"null_value\":0},\"cluster\":{\"type\":\"long\",\"null_value\":0},\"indices\":{\"type\":\"long\",\"null_value\":0}}},\"ui_reindex\":{\"properties\":{\"close\":{\"type\":\"long\",
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: t\"},\"hits\":{\"type\":\"integer\"},\"kibanaSavedObjectMeta\":{\"properties\":{\"searchSourceJSON\":{\"type\":\"text\"}}},\"sort\":{\"type\":\"keyword\"},\"title\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"vers
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: },\"timelion_sheet\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"title\":{\"type\":\"text\"},\"version\":{\"type\":\"integer\"}}},\"ui-metric\":{\"properties\":{\"count\":{\"type\":\"integer\"}}}},\"_meta\":{\"mig
Dec 11 10:03:14 mcjca033031 kibana[5320]: ",\"sample-data-telemetry\":\"7d3cfeb915303c9641c59681967ffeb4\",\"telemetry\":\"358ffaa88ba34a97d55af0933a117de4\",\"timelion-sheet\":\"9a2a2748877c7a7b582fef201ab1d4cf\",\"ui-metric\":\"0d4
Dec 11 10:03:15 mcjca033031 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 11 10:03:15 mcjca033031 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Dec 11 10:03:15 mcjca033031 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
```

**Elasticsearch.yml**

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: elasticsearchcluster
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
node.name: mcjca033078
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 11.208.33.78
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
discovery.seed_hosts: ["mcjca033078", "mcjca032215", "mcjca032254"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["mcjca033078", "mcjca032215", "mcjca032254"]

#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

**Kibana.yml**

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
server.port: 5601

# Specifies the address to which the Kibana server will bind. IP addresses and host names are both valid values.
# The default is 'localhost', which usually means remote machines will not be able to connect.
# To allow connections from remote users, set this parameter to a non-loopback address.
server.host: "mcjca033031"

# Enables you to specify a path to mount Kibana at if you are running behind a proxy.
# Use the `server.rewriteBasePath` setting to tell Kibana if it should remove the basePath
# from requests it receives, and to prevent a deprecation warning at startup.
# This setting cannot end in a slash.
#server.basePath: ""

# Specifies whether Kibana should rewrite requests that are prefixed with
# `server.basePath` or require that they are rewritten by your reverse proxy.
# This setting was effectively always `false` before Kibana 6.3 and will
# default to `true` starting in Kibana 7.0.
#server.rewriteBasePath: false

# The maximum payload size in bytes for incoming server requests.
#server.maxPayloadBytes: 1048576

# The Kibana server's name.  This is used for display purposes.
server.name: "mcjca033031"

# The URLs of the Elasticsearch instances to use for all your queries.
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://mcjca033078:9200", "http://mcjca032215:9200", "http://mcjca032254:9200"]

# When this setting's value is true Kibana uses the hostname specified in the server.host
# setting. When the value of this setting is false, Kibana uses the hostname of the host
# that connects to this Kibana instance.
#elasticsearch.preserveHost: true

# Kibana uses an index in Elasticsearch to store saved searches, visualizations and
# dashboards. Kibana creates a new index if the index doesn't already exist.
#kibana.index: ".kibana"

# The default application to load.
#kibana.defaultAppId: "home"

# If your Elasticsearch is protected with basic authentication, these settings provide
# the username and password that the Kibana server uses to perform maintenance on the Kibana
# index at startup. Your Kibana users still need to authenticate with Elasticsearch, which
# is proxied through the Kibana server.
#elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
#elasticsearch.password: "pass"

# Enables SSL and paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and SSL key files, respectively.
# These settings enable SSL for outgoing requests from the Kibana server to the browser.
#server.ssl.enabled: false
#server.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/server.crt
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key

# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.
# These files validate that your Elasticsearch backend uses the same key files.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 30000

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch at Kibana startup before retrying.
#elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000

# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch. Requires logging.verbose set to true.
#elasticsearch.logQueries: false

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
#pid.file: /var/run/kibana.pid

# Enables you specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
#logging.dest: stdout

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output.
#logging.silent: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output other than error messages.
#logging.quiet: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
#logging.verbose: false

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000.
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
# Supported languages are the following: English - en , by default , Chinese - zh-CN .
#i18n.locale: "en"
```

Also, when I run *ss -tunlp | grep 5601* during Kibana startup, I am seeing Kibana service is listening on 5601. However, in between multiple automatic attempts to connect to ES, it stops listening on 5601 and *ss -tunlp | grep 5601* returns nothing.

Comment: Does your `Kibana` work well with default settings for `kibana` and `elasticsearch`? Also please provide `kibana.yml` and `elasticsearch.yml`. Also you could try delete `kibana_1` index and let it be created again if that's fine with you.

Comment: Hi Kamil, I believe I am running with default settings. I've updated above question with kibana.yml and elasticsearch.yml. Also, kibana_1 index was not created for some reason. However, I do see .kibana_task_manager_1.

Comment: Show your indicies and mappings
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html 
Also what type of license do you have active now?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-license.html
What's status of `elasticsearch`?

Comment: 1. Here are my indices. I only have one: `green open .kibana_task_manager_1 tOVBApGdSFKfQpvReGCM7w 1 1 0 0 566b 283b`

2. When I try to get license, I'm getting this error: `"root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "invalid_index_name_exception",
        "reason" : "Invalid index name [_license], must not start with '_'.",
        "index_uuid" : "_na_",
        "index" : "_license"
      }
    ],`

Comment: Also, if it helps to know, this is a multi node elastic cluster.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/flattened.html
`flattened` is a type that is from `xpack`. Currently you do not have license, so you do not have `xpack`. You can install it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-xpack.html

But still fresh `Elastic stack` should work fine without it. Also you did not provide mapping for `.kibana_task_manager_1` index.
I am curious if deleting the index would help you. It's a default index so it's should be created again like `kibana` index i think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `FATAL  [mapper_parsing_exception] No handler for type [flattened]`

Use Elastic non-OSS v7.3+ or Kibana OSS.

The Kibana 7.5 non-OSS (basic) uses the `flattened` type available in the OSS version of Elasticsearch [7.3+](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/flattened.html).

The OSS version contains only features that are available under the Apache 2.0 license - https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

You can check it using `GET _nodes`:

```
{
  "name" : "flattened",
  "version" : "7.5.0",
  "elasticsearch_version" : "7.5.0",
  "java_version" : "1.8",
  "description" : "Module for the flattened field type, which allows JSON objects to be flattened into a single field.",
  "classname" : "org.elasticsearch.xpack.flattened.FlattenedMapperPlugin",
  "extended_plugins" : [
    "x-pack-core"
  ],
  "has_native_controller" : false
},
```

- Kibana OSS: `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana/kibana-oss-${VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
- Kibana non-OSS: `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana/kibana-${VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
- Elastic OSS: `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss-${VERSION}-no-jdk-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
- Elastic non-OSS: `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-${VERSION}-no-jdk-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`

Comment: Thank you. This was the problem.

Comment: If you are looking for the docker images: https://www.docker.elastic.co/r/kibana/kibana-oss