# Cannot start Kibana 7.5.0 Fatal Error have not done any changes in configuration file

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

Getting FATAL Error when starting Kibana 7.5, i have not configured anything i am just running elasticsearch.bat (also v7.5) and kibana.bat

```
'{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [flattened] declared on field [state]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: No handler for type [flattened] declared on field [state]",
"caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"No handler for type [flattened] declared on field [state]"}},"status":400}'
```

Also i was able start kibana 6.8.5 but could not connect to my elasticsearch node.

Comment: It might be related to https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/804 .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59288423/unable-to-connect-kibana-to-elasticsearch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same case: [Unable to connect Kibana to Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59288423/unable-to-connect-kibana-to-elasticsearch)

> `{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception",
>   "reason":"No handler for type [flattened] declared on field [state]"}`

Use Elastic non-OSS v7.3+ or Kibana OSS.

The Kibana 7.5 non-OSS (basic) uses the `flattened` type available in the OSS version of Elasticsearch [7.3+](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.3/flattened.html).

The OSS version contains only features that are available under the Apache 2.0 license - https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

You can check it using `GET _nodes`:

```
{
  "name" : "flattened",
  "version" : "7.5.0",
  "elasticsearch_version" : "7.5.0",
  "java_version" : "1.8",
  "description" : "Module for the flattened field type, which allows JSON objects to be flattened into a single field.",
  "classname" : "org.elasticsearch.xpack.flattened.FlattenedMapperPlugin",
  "extended_plugins" : [
    "x-pack-core"
  ],
  "has_native_controller" : false
},
```

- Kibana OSS: `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana/kibana-oss-${VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
- Kibana non-OSS: `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/kibana/kibana-${VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
- Elastic OSS: `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss-${VERSION}-no-jdk-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`
- Elastic non-OSS: `https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-${VERSION}-no-jdk-linux-x86_64.tar.gz`